# Rails ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in JobsController#show on clicking a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to open a job post on the show view but i get the error below.If i replace the find with find_by it works somehow but it gets only the first item of the active record.

> ```
> **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in JobsController#show**
> Couldn't find Job with 'id'=id
> ```

The model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :title, presence: true
validates :company, presence: true
validates :url, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

The Controller:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @jobs = Job.page(params[:page]).per(12) 
end

def show
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @job = Job.new
end

def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    if @job.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
  end
end 

 private
    def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:title, :company, :url)
  end

end
```

The index

```
<% @jobs.order("created_at desc").each do |job| %>

<p><%= link_to job.title, job_path(:id) %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view :

```
<% @jobs.order("created_at desc").each do |job| %>

<p><%= link_to job.title, job_path(job) %></p>
<% end %>
```